# Issue to hide Toolbar when scrolling in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design

I've an Activity with an NavigationDrawer and a Toolbar. I'm facing a problem when i want disappear a toobar when one of child fragment view is scrolled. Everything works fine except that there is some view coming up from the bottom which has the exact same size as the toolbar that is disappearing.

I made an GIF Animation that shows the problem. Due to my reputation i can not post the image directly but [this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe5Tl.gif) and [this gif](http://i.giphy.com/3oEduZPUZv5QvUIigo.gif) shows the problem

I tried to figure out where this is coming from. It seems that its from my container FrameLayout where my fragment views are placed during runtime. I changed its background to green so i can identify it.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/darkGreen"
        tools:context="org.cddevlib.breathe.MainActivity" />
</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="org.cddevlib.breathe.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" /> </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the Toolbars Layout that is included

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And finally a snippet from the fragments view that is loaded:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black" >

   <include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        (...)
```

Note that i'm including the Toolbar again in that layout because i want different Toolbars for each fragment in my application by hiding / adding the toolbar.

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) ((View) vw).findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            if (toolbar != null) {
                // // for crate home button
                activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
                activity.getSupportActionBar().hide();
                toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable((ColorUtils.getColorDark(DataModule.getInstance()
                        .getMainActivity()))));
                activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            }
```

**SOLUTION**

So thanks to sanat shukla answer is firgured out that my problem was that i used an AppBarLayout too much in my fragments view. In my fragments view, AppBarLayout was the main layout for all of my components, but it should not! Its intended to hold the toolbar content! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue. It is the cool animation and support provided by android. When you use co-ordinator layout with Toolbar then it shows cool animation when scrolling the list.

> The Design library takes this to the next level: using an AppBarLayout
>   allows your Toolbar and other views (such as tabs provided by
>   TabLayout) to react to scroll events in a sibling view marked with a
>   ScrollingViewBehavior

Read from here :
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

If you don't want to hide your toolbar then don't use co-ordinator layout and appbar with toolbar.

Try this for fragment :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <! -- Your Scrollable View -->
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:fillViewport="true" >
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView/>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: actually i want that animation but i do not want the green bar at the bottom as shown here http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe5Tl.gif.

Comment: its not a bar. its your framelayout

Comment: yes thank you it seems to be my FrameLayout that is showing up at the bottom. But why? I changed my NestedScrollViews layout to yours but it had no effect

Comment: Am i using the correct Layout (FrameLayout) for my fragments as the container?

Comment: @Christian Dud You added two AppBar layout one in your toolbar file and one in your fragment. In your toolbar file just add toolbar only and remove coordinator layout from there. Then add Coordinator layout to your fragment with AppBar layout.

Comment: thank you. i see that the additional AppBarLayout was not necessary and removed it from my toolbar.xml. Its still the same effect with the FrameLayout popping up from the bottom :-(

Comment: @Christian Dud Check my edited answer set your fragment file like above answer and in toolbar file just use toolbar only. Don't put coordinator layout and appbar layout in toolbar file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i figured out that my problem was that i used two AppBarLayouts